# Guidence on buliding a Django model

Tags: django, django-3.0

I am trying to build a job tracker, I have a Job model where the admin can create a job, then here's where it gets tricky for me.
The employee can go to the jobs sections, check out the job, then record the start time and end time. Then display the total time worked on the job. Each time the employee works on the job it will update the total time. My initial model looks like this but not sure how to handle the start, end, and total times. I would appreciate any guidance.

```
  class TaskModel(models.Model):
    """
        Using many to many field because incase a user checks out more than one job. Maybe a 
        better solution?
    """
    PROGRESS_STATUS = [
        ('IN PROGRESS', 'In Progress'),
        ('COMPLETE', 'Complete')
    ]
    intern = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ManyToManyField("app.Model", verbose_name="")(JobModel, verbose_name="jobs", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    progress = models.CharField(choices=PROGRESS_STATUS, default="In Progress", max_length=20)
    start_time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    total_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    checkout_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: looks good at first sight. What guidance exactly do you need? Maybe specify.

Comment: Hi Ben, is this the correct way to set it up models to automatically update the end time and total on a button click?

Comment: I guess you may do it like this. start_time will fill automatically and you'll need an additional function to insert end_time whenever you set a progess to 'Complete' and calculate total_time by calculating the difference between end_time and start_time returning an integer value in a defined unit, e.g. days / minutes, whatever suits you.

Comment: But you could also define a function returning total_time as the difference between start_time and end_time. Because total_time is entirely dependent on start_time and end_time, so you make sure that your database is in canonical form. :)